# Let $f(x)=\int_0^xe^{x-y}f'(y)dy-(x^2-x+1)e^x$ Find the number of roots of the equation $f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)=\int_0^xe^{x-y}f'(y)dy-(x^2-x+1)e^x$ Find the number of roots of the equation $f(x)=0$

---

$f(x)=\int_0^xe^{x-y}f'(y)dy-(x^2-x+1)e^x=e^x\int_0^xe^{-y}f'(y)dy-(x^2-x+1)e^x$
I tried to solve $\int_0^xe^{-y}f'(y)dy$ by integration by parts by taking $e^{-y}$ as first function and $f'(y)$ as second function.
I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Try differentiating. If my calculations are correct you get $f'(x)=\int_0^xe^{x-y}f'(y)dy-(x^2-x+1)e^x+e^xe^{-x}f'(x)-(2x-1)e^x=f(x)+f'(x)-(2x-1)e^x$ and thus $f(x)=(2x-1)e^x$. Now it is easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: rewrite as
$$
\newcommand\e{\mathrm e} 
\newcommand\diff{\,\mathrm d}
\e^{-x}f(x) = \int_0^x \e^{-y}f'(y)\diff y - (x^2-x+1),
$$
now take the derivatives.